# Get device current language in English language in ios 10 and above?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to get language name selected by the user device.
I got language id and it's display name

```
  NSString *langID = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
  NSLog(@"langID %@",langID);
  lang = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode value:langID];
  NSLog(@"lang %@",lang);
```

If I select device language as 'Chinese Traditional',the output is 
      `langID zh-Hant-US display name 中文`.

I want to display name in the English language like 'Chinese', not in the Chinese language. So my question is "Is it possible to get language name in English?" If yes then "How can we achieve it?" any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
  NSString *langID = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
  NSLocale *local = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"];
  NSString * lang = [local displayNameForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode value:langID];
```

Comment: It didn't help me. In this example you set localeWithLocaleIdentifier initially, but I need to get device language which is set by user.

Comment: yes , l langID  is the device language id . it is only convert your string language